# Angular @Input message is set only for the first time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following component for receiving a message from child component and showing it:

**TypeScript**

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Admin Notification Component
 *
 * @export
 * @class NotificationComponent
 * @implements {OnInit}
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'manager-notification',
    templateUrl: 'notification.component.html'
})

export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    /**
     * Alert message to show
     *
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof NotificationComponent
     */
    // @Input() public message: string | Array<string>;
    @Input() public message: any;


    /**
     * Component Init
     *
     * @memberof NotificationComponent
     */
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initContent();
    }

    /**
     * Handle any changes
     *
     * @param {SimpleChanges} changes
     * @memberof NotificationComponent
     */
    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.initContent();
    }

    /**
     * Format message for alerts
     *
     * @returns {string}
     * @memberof NotificationComponent
     */
    public formatMessage(): string {

        // If message is an array
        if (_.isArray(this.message)) {
            return _.join(this.message, '<br />');
        }

        return this.message;
    }

    /**
     * Close notification
     */
    public close()
    {
        this.message = null;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize content
     *
     * @private
     * @memberof NotificationComponent
     */
    private initContent() {

        // Dismiss global notifications after 10 seconds
        if (this.message) {
            setTimeout(() => this.message = null, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="app-alert_layout" *ngIf="message">
    <div class="alert alert-success app-alert_layout-structure" role="alert" id="success_alert">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-sm-between align-items-center app-alert_content-icon">
            <i class="material-icons app-alert_content-icon">info_outline</i>
            <p class="app-alert_content" [innerHTML]="formatMessage()">&nbsp;<br></p>
            <a class="alert-link app-alert_content-close" id="alert_close" href="JavaScript:void(0)" (click)="close()">
                <i class="material-icons app-alert_content-close-icon">close</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in the child component template I have

```
<manager-notification [message]="noPermissionMessage"></manager-notification>
```

and I am setting the `noPermissionMessage` text in a menu click as follows:

```
if (this.noPermission) {
    this.noPermissionMessage ="Your current role doesn't allow this action !!";
    return false;
}
```

When I click on the first time, everything is working fine. The notification is shown and vanishes after the specified time. Now for the second time, it is not showing the notification. It is setting the message, but the notification is not shown. How this can be fixed ?

Comment: First you should not be updating the input variable message from your component. Second if you use `push`, `unshift` to add elements to your array, it will mutate and change detection won't be able to notice. Try using the spread operator and creating a new instance of array after each change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is that the `noPermissionMessage` is not changing.

Change your code inside your child component like this.

```
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

/**
 * Alert message to show
 *
 * @type {string}
 * @memberof NotificationComponent
 */
// @Input() public message: string | Array<string>;
@Input() public message: string;
@Output() public messageChange = new EventEmitter<string>();  // CHANGE HERE


/**
 * Component Init
 *
 * @memberof NotificationComponent
 */
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initContent();
}

/**
 * Handle any changes
 *
 * @param {SimpleChanges} changes
 * @memberof NotificationComponent
 */
public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.initContent();
}

/**
 * Format message for alerts
 *
 * @returns {string}
 * @memberof NotificationComponent
 */
public formatMessage(): string {

    // If message is an array
    if (_.isArray(this.message)) {
        return _.join(this.message, '<br />');
    }

    return this.message;
}

/**
 * Close notification
 */
public close()
{
    this.message = null;
}

/**
 * Initialize content
 *
 * @private
 * @memberof NotificationComponent
 */
private initContent() {

    // Dismiss global notifications after 5 seconds
    if (this.message) {
        setTimeout(() => this.messageChange.emit(null), 5000); // CHANGE HERE
    }
}
}
```

After that you can have two-way data binding on your component

`<manager-notification [(message)]="noPermissionMessage"></manager-notification>`

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that you have to change the reference of your input so try to use an array instead like :

```js
this.noPermissionMessage =["Your current role doesn't allow this action !!"];
```